# Gene expression changes in one condition

Tags: rna-seq, differential-expression

I want to look at an RNA-seq data-set on 1 condition to look for expressed genes. As there is only one condition, I can’t perform differential analysis.

The only thing I can think to do is set a threshold (i.e. all replicates must have > 10 gene counts) then say these are expressed. But I don’t think this is a very good way of doing it.

Do you know of any better ways that we can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you've got enough replicates (ideally at least 6, but can be done with 3), you should be able to do a Variance-stabilised Transformation using DESeq2:

```
vsd <- vst(dds, blind=FALSE)
rld <- rlog(dds, blind=FALSE)
head(assay(vsd), 3)
```

More details on this can be found in the DESeq2 Vignette:

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#extracting-transformed-values

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from @james-hawley, converted from [comment](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):*

In any high throughput sequencing experiment, there will be lowly expressed RNA molecules that are not captured by the library prep + sequencing. So defining what "is expressed" is somewhat arbitrary from RNA-seq data, regardless of how many replicates you have and what method you use. That said, you can control some of the noise in your RNA-seq data using a variance-stabilized transformation, like @gringer suggests, and look at the distribution of genes/transcripts. Some threshold like $rlog \ge x$ in at least $n$ samples is usually a good starting point (for some arbitrary $x$ and $n$).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a very good way to do what you want to do.  I'd think some kind of RPM would be better than strictly raw counts; you have to account for overall library size.  Or TPM might be better.